did_multiplegt_dyn with controlvariables
I run a staggered DiD regression with the Stata command did_multiplegt_dyn by De Chaisemartin, C., & d'Haultfoeuille, X. (2024). Without control vars the command runs
# Comand without controls 
did_multiplegt_dyn outcome PLZ year treat_dummy, effects(8) placebo(6) cluster(PLZ)



as soon as I include control variables, even only one without any missings e.g., age I get the error: " no observations"
# Comand with controls 
did_multiplegt_dyn outcome PLZ year treat_dummy, effects(8) placebo(6) cluster(PLZ) controls(age)

has anyone an idea what the problem is here?
I tried different control variables but the problem prevails

Compare answers at https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1749128-did_multiplegt_dyn-control-variables
